# touchpad not working (at all) in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, startup, synaptics

I am new to Linux. I don't know why my touch pad is not working at all. But the mouse is working perfectly well. Please help

Comment: Is there a button to turn off/on the touchpad? Have you tried pushing it? Just to get the obvious out of the way.

Comment: I am seeing my touchpad (on HP Mini 210) not working for up to 220s (nearly 4 minutes) after startup, on both **13.10** and **14.04 beta**. *Can you confirm that touchpad is not working at all?*

Comment: What is the output from: **`dmesg | grep Touch`** ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a tips

Before you log in when at LightDM state (before you fill your password), try to turn on your touchpad with Fn + key. Every laptop has different key. Mine is Fn + F7.

maybe this can help. :-)

If above method are success, probably it's a bug. You can report it to launchpad.